# Action method not called when IIS error occurs, just blank page with 403 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to capture IIS errors but not winning at all. Besides the errors thrown by ASP.NET, I would also like to capture all errors that originate from IIS. I started to experiment with `404` errors, I could have chosen any other error, but chose 404 as a starting point.

I am using the latest version of `ASP.NET MVC5` and running the website through `IIS 7.5`.

I have the following set in my `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/Http404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

I have the following in my error controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Http404()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        return View();
    }
}
```

I am throwing the error like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

Given my settings in the web.config my action method in the error controller is not hit. I have seen people capture the error in the `Application_Error` method, but the above code doesn't reach my Application_Error method. All that I can see is a blank page with a 403 error status.

Why do people set the above code like mine but then in the error controller they still go and set the error controller and the action method to be called, isn't this duplicating work? Why do I get a 403 error returned with a blank page?

Please don't close this question as a duplicate but please help me fix it. I have worked through almost all the questions given here on SO.

This is so frustrating.

Comment: because it is not throwing any error

Comment: Is this the same as a 404 error thrown by IIS? If IIS throws this error then I need to capture it but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Go to FilterConfig.cs inside App-Start folder.
Add the exception type and error page you want for the specific type of exception.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new LoggingExceptionFilter());
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute() { ExceptionType = typeof(Exception), View = "Error" }, 1);
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute() { ExceptionType = typeof(HttpException), View = "HttpExceptionError" }, 2);

        }
```

Create a view with name `HttpExceptionError` in **SHARED folder**.